# Hibernate logging, how to show the implicit operations?

Tags: hibernate, log4j

I am using Hibernate as JPA provider.
I would like to know the exact behavior of my application, I want to know all the implicit operations (that I do not call explicitly in my code) that Hibernate executing.
Example:

What are the queries that hibernate executes for the initial loading of objects from the database?
When hibernate call flush() or commit()?

In my persistence.xml file I am using the property:
    
And I also using log4j logger:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG, SQL_APPENDER
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false
```

But I do not see this kind of information.

Am I missing some property or jog4j settings? or there is no way to track this kind of operation.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have set additivity to false for the hibernate logger, you will need to attach a separate appender to it or else it will not anything.